# How to use grunt sass to compile and compress scss to css?

Tags: css, gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt-contrib-sass in order to compile ...

Basically I want to achieve the following

```
sass --compass --force --update --style compressed --sourcemap /scss:/css
```

I tried the following

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                '/css/screen.css': '/screen.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

However, grunt is complainaing "**Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen**"

Any idea how to fix this? It also uses compass by the way.. Do I need that defined in grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use grunt-sass as well and my usual SASS config looks like this:

```
client: {
    options: {
        loadPath: ['<%= config.tmp %>/styles'],
        compass: false
    },
    files: {
        '<%= config.tmp %>/styles/main.css': '<%= config.tmp %>/styles/main.scss'
    }
}
```